# How to get multiline for a Jlist text?

Tags: java, multiline, jlist

I have a problem in get mutiline for Jlist !

Do you have any idiea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what have you tried so far?
Try implementing a custom **ListCellRenderer**.
More information [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=338653).

Comment: Thanks !

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=552711 this is a sample !